# What's the difference about using Langchain's Retrieval with .from_llm or defining LLMChain?

Tags: python, openai-api, information-retrieval, langchain, large-language-model

In the documentation, I've seen two patterns of construction and I'm a bit confused about the difference between both. I don't know if there's any actual difference or if just the same thing in different approach.

Example 1 (using .from_llm):

```
model = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0.3)
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
vectordb = Chroma(embedding_function=embeddings, persist_directory=directory)
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)
qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    model,
    vectordb.as_retriever(),
    condense_question_prompt=CUSTOM_QUESTION_PROMPT,
    memory=memory
)
query = "What did the president say about Ketanji Brown Jackson"
result = qa({"question": query})
```

Example 2 (no method, with LLMChain):

```
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)
question_generator = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT)
doc_chain = load_qa_with_sources_chain(llm, chain_type="map_reduce")

chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain(
    retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(),
    question_generator=question_generator,
    combine_docs_chain=doc_chain,
)
chat_history = []
query = "What did the president say about Ketanji Brown Jackson"
result = chain({"question": query, "chat_history": chat_history})
```

I can see that in the second example I'm defining the model and prompt separately as a question_generator that I pass as an argument in the chain aftwerwards. Thus, I'm passing a doc_chain.

But I've some abstract doubts, such as what's underneath, what are the consequences, when should I use one or another, if it's the same output etc. Mostly, is the first simple example somehow using a question_generator or a doc_chain which are omitted in the code?

Answer (score 2):

=> .from_llm:
This approach is more high-level and abstracted.
.from_llm is a method that pre-configures a chain given an LLM (Language Model), with some predefined settings.
The main advantage is simplicity and less room for error, especially for users who don't want to dive deep into the details.

=> (no method, with LLMChain):
This approach is more granular and explicit.
You are explicitly constructing each part of the chain and then assembling them together.
By separating out the llm, question_generator, and doc_chain, you have more control and flexibility. You can customize each part as per your requirements.
This method is for users who want fine-grained control over the chain's behavior, potentially at the expense of increased complexity.

Underneath: The underlying mechanism is likely similar , but the specifics of how the model is used, how questions are generated, and how documents are combined might vary between the two methods, especially based on the configurations used.

Comment: Thank you! You are precise and now I'm sure about the differences. I've made the right decision and opted to advanced using the more granular one, tweaking a lot, and I've achieved a nice result. Now I'm getting some bugs by dealing with QA prompts and doc_chain prompts, imput_variables, chain_types (stuff, refine, map_rerank) and output_parsers. It's a bit confusing. But I will open a new question about it.

Answer (score 0):

this is the source code of `from_llm` [from github](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/master/libs/langchain/langchain/chains/conversational_retrieval/base.py)

```
 @classmethod
    def from_llm(
        cls,
        llm: BaseLanguageModel,
        retriever: BaseRetriever,
        condense_question_prompt: BasePromptTemplate = CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT,
        chain_type: str = "stuff",
        verbose: bool = False,
        condense_question_llm: Optional[BaseLanguageModel] = None,
        combine_docs_chain_kwargs: Optional[Dict] = None,
        callbacks: Callbacks = None,
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> BaseConversationalRetrievalChain:
        """Convenience method to load chain from LLM and retriever.

        This provides some logic to create the `question_generator` chain
        as well as the combine_docs_chain.

        Args:
            llm: The default language model to use at every part of this chain
                (eg in both the question generation and the answering)
            retriever: The retriever to use to fetch relevant documents from.
            condense_question_prompt: The prompt to use to condense the chat history
                and new question into a standalone question.
            chain_type: The chain type to use to create the combine_docs_chain, will
                be sent to `load_qa_chain`.
            verbose: Verbosity flag for logging to stdout.
            condense_question_llm: The language model to use for condensing the chat
                history and new question into a standalone question. If none is
                provided, will default to `llm`.
            combine_docs_chain_kwargs: Parameters to pass as kwargs to `load_qa_chain`
                when constructing the combine_docs_chain.
            callbacks: Callbacks to pass to all subchains.
            **kwargs: Additional parameters to pass when initializing
                ConversationalRetrievalChain
        """
        combine_docs_chain_kwargs = combine_docs_chain_kwargs or {}
        doc_chain = load_qa_chain(
            llm,
            chain_type=chain_type,
            verbose=verbose,
            callbacks=callbacks,
            **combine_docs_chain_kwargs,
        )

        _llm = condense_question_llm or llm
        condense_question_chain = LLMChain(
            llm=_llm,
            prompt=condense_question_prompt,
            verbose=verbose,
            callbacks=callbacks,
        )
        return cls(
            retriever=retriever,
            combine_docs_chain=doc_chain,
            question_generator=condense_question_chain,
            callbacks=callbacks,
            **kwargs,
        )
```

its comment says

> This provides some logic to create the `question_generator` chain
> as well as the combine_docs_chain.

If you examine the source code, you create those functionalities only with `from_llm` method. explanation of those functionalities [from here](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/master/libs/langchain/langchain/chains/conversational_retrieval/base.py)

> This chain has two steps. First, it condenses the current question and
> the chat history into a standalone question. This is necessary to
> create a standanlone vector to use for retrieval. After that, it does
> retrieval and then answers the question using retrieval augmented
> generation with a separate model. Part of the power of the declarative
> nature of LangChain is that you can easily use a separate language
> model for each call. This can be useful to use a cheaper and faster
> model for the simpler task of condensing the question, and then a more
> expensive model for answering the question.